# Printing fieldable panel pane custom field in template properly

Tags: theming

I've created a fieldable panel pane that has two fields, a title and a body. My template file looks like this:

```
<div class="sidebar-pane">
    <h2 class="pane-title">
        <?php print render($content['field_pane_title']); ?>
    </h2>
    <div class="pane-content">
        <?php print render($content['field_body']); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This seems fairly basic. Now, when I actually add one of these panes to a page, this is the DOM that is spit out:

```
<div class="sidebar-pane">
    <h2 class="pane-title"></h2>
    <h3 class="field-label"></h3>
    Test Pane   

    <div class="pane-content">
        <h3 class="field-label"></h3>

        <p>This is a test body.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ignoring the fact that it's printing out empty field-label elements, why is the pane-title field being printed outside the pane-title h2 element? Is there a better way to be doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the empty field-labels was a problem! The issue was with those field labels, which were generated by the Fences module. They were somehow causing the h2 to close too early.

I ended up modifying the module myself, so that the template checks if a field label exists before adding it to the DOM.

I also ended up finding an issue on the module's issue page which has a patch to fix it directly, in case anyone is interested: https://www.drupal.org/node/2605808